# Android gradle plugin v3.3.0 -> can't find R$raw when using proguard

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

Just updated to Android gradle plugin version 3.3.0

We have the following setup (not sure which are important):

- Application project (app) with 3 library modules (data, domain, utils)
- Databinding enabled (`databinding.enabled true`)
- Proguard enabled(`proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'`)

**When I build the app using:**

`./gradlew assembleDevRelease`

I get the following error:

`can't find referenced class my.package.data.R$raw`

**When I build the app using:**

`./gradlew :app:assembleDevRelease`

The app builds fine, generates an obfuscated *.apk which I can install

**Question:**

- What's the difference between `assembleRelease` and `:app:assembleRelease`

<s>- Why does switching to android gradle plugin 3.3.0 affect which task I have to call to build my apk? We use `assembleRelease` everywhere in our CI pipelines to build our apks.</s>

- What changed in android gradle plugin 3.3.0 that caused the task `assembleRelease` to break? We use `assembleRelease` everywhere in our CI pipelines to build our apks.
- Any suggestions how we can make 'assembleRelease' working again? (update Proguard config?, enabling R8?)

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between `assembleRelease` and `:app:assembleRelease`

The former runs the `assembleRelease` task on all modules relative to current level. The latter runs it on the `app` module only (and its dependencies).

> Why does switching to android gradle plugin 3.3.0 affect which task I have to call to build my apk? We use `assembleRelease` everywhere in our CI pipelines to build our apks.

The question does not have enough info to say for sure, but there are a number of changes listed in the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-3-0). For example, this issue might be related to:

> **Faster R class generation for library projects:** Previously, the Android Gradle plugin would generate an `R.java` file for each of your project's dependencies and then compile those R classes alongside your app's other classes. The plugin now generates a JAR containing your app's compiled R class directly, without first building intermediate `R.java` classes. This optimization may significantly improve build performance for projects that include many library subprojects and dependencies, and improve the indexing speed in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, i'm pretty sure that change is related to the problem we're facing. But I have no clue where to look for "restoring" the old behaviour. Or what to disable.

Comment: We simply started using `app:assembleRelease` everywhere in our build pipelines. 
In our case, that causes the build to be slightly faster and the problem went away...
At the moment, we are using version 3.5.1 and I have not checked if the problem is still present in that version.